# Wrong column padding with Bootstrap SASS grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, pug

I have a minimal Bootstrap-SASS setup that doesn't behave well. It's basically a three-column template, where CSS elements are generated via mixins. With the following code the third, rightmost column wraps under the first one, which is an unwanted behavior. Here is a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/xz3udwnhz/

I think it's a matter of insufficient space: if I remove the 15px column padding from each column (manually, via Chrome dev tools) they fit nicely inside the container.

This is the `main.sass`:

```
/* minimal Bootstrap-SASS */
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables"
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins"
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/normalize"
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/utilities"
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/responsive-utilities"

/* entry point */
@import "base"
```

This is `base.sass`:

```
.container
  @include container-fixed()

.row
  @include make-row()

.col
  @include make-md-column(4)
```

And this is the `index.html` (in Jade, for brevity's sake):

```
doctype html
html(lang="en") 
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(href='styles/main.css', media='all', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')

  body
    div(class='container')
      div(class='row')
        div(class='col') col
        div(class='col') col
        div(class='col') col
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't get this question. You've virtually said you're code isn't working, but have hardly helped *describe* the issue fully, let alone provided a minimal and complete question.

Comment: Hi jbutler483, I have edited my question and attached a screenshot. Hope it helps :)

Comment: change the width to 30%? (or 33.33% - padding - margins)

Comment: The "33.33% - padding - margins" solution works fine (except that I lose side padding), but I wonder why I don't have to do that with the non-SASS version of Bootstrap...

Comment: IMHO: i'd move away from bootstrap - it's great for a 'quick demo/plan', but for proper web stuff, it becomes more hindrance than help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use box-sizing: border-box. so The width of your rows is 33% + 15*2px (2 paddings). That's why your third row shifted on second line. For a minimal Bootstrap-SASS setup which can run you need to connect _scaffolding.scss including method 'box-sizing: border-box' for all elements. The border-box value (as opposed to the content-box default) makes the final rendered box the declared width, and any border and padding cut inside the box. We can now safely declare our textarea to be of 33% width, including pixel-based padding and border, and accomplish out layout perfectly.